# How to change cmake protobuff working directory/path?

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers

I want to compile and generate library from protobuf using cmake. But I cannot assign a proto file path in CMakeLists.txt. The problem is that other .proto file using relative import from a parent folder ( import "modules/common/proto/abc.pb.h") cannot recognize the imported proto correctly.

Different file path in direct protoc command will generate different namespace:

```
protoc --cpp_out=proto proto/person.proto (namespace is protobuf_proto_2fperson_2eproto)
```

and

```
protoc --cpp_out=./ person.proto (namespace is protobuf_person_2eproto)
```

How to make it in CMakeLists.txt and generate the .cc file using structured namespace like protobuf_proto_2fperson_2eproto? Thanks.

My files list as below:

```
../test/
`-- proto
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- demo.proto
    `-- person.proto
```

in demo.proto:

```
syntax = "proto2";

package tutorial;

import "proto/person.proto";

message AddressBook {
  repeated Person people = 1;
}
```

in person.proto:

```
syntax = "proto2";

package tutorial;

message Person {
  required string name = 1;
}
```

My CMakeLists.txt is：

```
PROJECT(tutorial)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)

set(PROTOBUF_IMPORT_DIRS "../")

include_directories(
${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

file(GLOB ProtoFiles "*.proto")

protobuf_generate_cpp(ProtoSources ProtoHeaders ${ProtoFiles})

add_library(proto SHARED ${ProtoSources} ${ProtoHeaders})
target_link_libraries(proto ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES})
set_target_properties(proto PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```